# Reading all values from certain columns in csv into one array python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have data in csv format of the following form:

```
A   B   a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
1   0   100 34  44  1   1
2   0   101 1   44  11  3
3   0   105 3   55  21  22
4   0   45  4   52  1   45
5   0   57  5   42  3   56
6   0   89  78  1   3   67
7   0   34  99  2   4   98
8   0   57  23  2   5   2
```

I would like to store the data from columns a1 on in one array to give:

```
100
34
44
1
1
101
1
44
.
.
```

I can do this using python by reading the columns I want from the csv into a pandas dataframe. Converting each column into an array, looping through each array, and appending the values to one new array. I know this  is very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) with selecting columns by columns names:

```
A = df[['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']].values.ravel()
```

Or by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
A = df.filter(like='a').values.ravel()
```

Or by position - from second column to end:

```
A = df.iloc[:, 2:].values.ravel()
```

---

```
print (A)
[100  34  44   1   1 101   1  44  11   3 105   3  55  21  22  45   4  52
   1  45  57   5  42   3  56  89  78   1   3  67  34  99   2   4  98  57
  23   2   5   2]
```

Comment: @Sjoseph - Glad can help! Small advice - For prevent downvotes add some code, error, what you try.